# Paste/insert onto the end of multiple lines - latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a long list in latex, without "\\" in the end, so the text is without newlines each time. I have over 5000 lines of this, and would therefore like to insert "\\" onto everyline in one go. I am trying to convert/copy a pdf to latex, but the converters online can't get it right.
Right now it looks like this:
[image: current look]

Is this possible, or even better, get it to look like this at the same time:

[image: Desired look]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\obeylines` to keep your line breaks

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
{
\obeylines
test
test
}   
\end{document}
```